# draw connector on two mouse clicks in javascript

Tags: javascript, connector

I have below code where i have dynamically created circles which are drag-gable. I need to create a connector between two drag-gable circles using js. I am using d3 library. on click i get the co ordinates but not sure how to proceed further. when two clicks on any of the dynamically created circles one connector should get created and it should also be drag-gable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
    .mybutton {
    background:#0000FF;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:20px;
    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
    }
    #root {
    background:#FFFF00;
    }
    #service{
    background:#00FF00;
    }
    #divContainer, #divResize { 
            border:dashed 1px #CCC; 
            width:120px; 
            height:120px; 
            padding:5px; 
            margin:5px; 
            font:13px Arial; 
            cursor:move; 
            float:left 
        } 
    .division{
        border:solid 3px #CCC; 
        width:90%;
        height:750px;
        float:right;
    }       
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="drawArea" class="division" ></div>
        <div id="firstDivision" >
        <form id="test2">
        <input type="button" id="root" class="mybutton" /> Root <p>
        <input type="button" id="service" class="mybutton"/ > Service<p>
        <input type="button" id="action1" class="mybutton" draggable="true"/ > Action
        </form>
        </div>
        <canvas id="example" class="division">

        </canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          // Create a svg canvas
          var svg = d3.select("#drawArea")
            .append("svg")
          .attr("width", 700)
          .attr("height", 500);

          //Drag nodes
          var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
              .on("dragstart", function() {
                  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
              })
              .on("drag", dragmove)
              .on("dragend",dragended);

          //First circle
          var g1 = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 150 + "," + 100 + ")")
            .attr("class", "first")
            .call(drag)
            .append("circle").attr({
              r: 20,
            })
            .style("fill", "#FFFF00")

          //Second cicle
          var g2 = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 300 + ")")
            .attr("class", "second")
            .call(drag)
            .append("circle").attr({
              r: 20,
            })
            .style("fill", "#00FF00")

        svg.on('dblclick', function() {
            var coords = d3.mouse(this);
            console.log(coords);
            drawCircle(coords[0], coords[1]);
        });
        svg.on('click',function(){
            var coords = d3.mouse(this);
            var classFirst = d3.select(this).attr("class");
            drawConnector(coords[0], coords[1]);
        });

        //draw connector
        function drawConnector(x, y) {
        var c=document.getElementById("example");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(150,100);
        ctx.lineTo(250,300);
        ctx.stroke();
        }

        //third circle on click     
        function drawCircle(x, y) {
            var g2 = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
            .attr("class", "action")
            .call(drag)
            .append("circle").attr({
              r: 20,
            })
            .style("fill", "#00F");     
        }


          //Drag handler
          function dragmove(d) {
              var x = d3.event.x;
              var y = d3.event.y;
              d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
              if(d3.select(this).attr("class") == "first") {
                /*line.attr("x1", x);
                line.attr("y1", y);*/
                d3.select(this).attr("cx", x);
                d3.select(this).attr("cy", y);               
              } else {
                d3.select(this).attr("cx", x);
                d3.select(this).attr("cy", y);
                /*line.attr("x2", x);
                line.attr("y2", y);*/
              }
          }

    function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
    }           

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

g1 and g2 were being set to the circle elements so they weren't usable without adjustment.  Now we can use g1 and g2 to get the translation's of the circle containers and use that to draw the line.

```js
// Create a svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#drawArea")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 700)
.attr("height", 500);

//Drag nodes
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("dragstart", function() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
})
.on("drag", dragmove)
.on("dragend", dragended);

// ADDED c1 AND c2 below.  g1 AND g2 WERE BEING SET TO CIRCLES.

//First circle
var g1 = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 150 + "," + 100 + ")")
.attr("class", "first")
.call(drag);
var c1= g1.append("circle").attr({
  r: 20,
})
.style("fill", "#FFFF00")

//Second cicle
var g2 = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 300 + ")")
.attr("class", "second")
.call(drag);
var c2 = g2.append("circle").attr({
  r: 20,
})
.style("fill", "#00FF00");

// ADD LINE ELEMENT
var line = svg.append("line")
.attr({x1: 150, y1: 100, x2: 250, y2: 300})
.attr({"stroke-width": 2, stroke: "red"});

svg.on('dblclick', function() {
  var coords = d3.mouse(this);
  console.log(coords);
  drawCircle(coords[0], coords[1]);
});
svg.on('click', function() {
  var coords = d3.mouse(this);
  var classFirst = d3.select(this).attr("class");
  drawConnector(coords[0], coords[1]);
});

//draw connector
function drawConnector(g1, g2) {
  // MOVE LINE WITH TRANSFORMS OF G ELEMENTS.
  var t1 = g1.attr("transform").replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").split(",");
  var t2 = g2.attr("transform").replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").split(",");
  line.attr({x1: t1[0], y1: t1[1], x2: t2[0], y2: t2[1]});
}

//third circle on click     
function drawCircle(x, y) {
  var g2 = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
  .attr("class", "action")
  .call(drag)
  .append("circle").attr({
    r: 20,
  })
  .style("fill", "#00F");
}


//Drag handler
function dragmove(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x;
  var y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
  if (d3.select(this).attr("class") == "first") {
    /*line.attr("x1", x);
             line.attr("y1", y);*/
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", x);
    d3.select(this).attr("cy", y);
  } else {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", x);
    d3.select(this).attr("cy", y);
    /*line.attr("x2", x);
             line.attr("y2", y);*/
  }
  drawConnector(g1, g2);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

```css
.mybutton {
  background: #0000FF;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
#root {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
#service {
  background: #00FF00;
}
#divContainer,
#divResize {
  border: dashed 1px #CCC;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  font: 13px Arial;
  cursor: move;
  float: left
}
.division {
  border: solid 3px #CCC;
  width: 90%;
  height: 750px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="drawArea" class="division"></div>
  <div id="firstDivision">
    <form id="test2">
      <input type="button" id="root" class="mybutton" />Root
      <p>
        <input type="button" id="service" class="mybutton" />Service
        <p>
          <input type="button" id="action1" class="mybutton" draggable="true" />Action
    </form>
  </div>
  <canvas id="example" class="division"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what i am exactly looking for is: on single click of any two circles I should be able to draw a connector(line) between them. example: I click on circle "second" and next click on circle "third" which gets created dynamically( on dblclick function), there should be a connector(line) created between second and third circle which is drag-gable along with the circles. this applied to all the dynamically created circles. The end product of the exercise is a drag able tree structure.